# Integrate Xdebug in PhpStorm with docker for Magento 2

Tags: docker, phpstorm, magento2, xdebug

I have a Magento 2 project which has a Docker environment and we're running it on Docker. It is running fine but for debugging some issues I opened it with PhpStorm and now want to integrate Xdebug for docker environment.

I followed some articles and videos and from their mentioned steps, I did the following:

my DockerFile:

```
...

RUN pecl install xdebug-3.1.6 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
...
```

Docker-compose.yml

```yaml
...
  app:
   build:
     context: .
   ports:
     - "80:80"
   volumes:
     - ./scripts/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
     - ./app/:/var/www/html/app/
     - ./nginx.conf/:/var/www/html/nginx.conf
   extra_hosts:
    - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
   working_dir: /var/www/html/
   depends_on:
     db:
       condition: service_started
     elasticsearch:
       condition: service_started
     rabbitmq:
       condition: service_started
     redis:
       condition: service_started
...
```

php.ini

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.start_with_request= yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=0
xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal
xdebug.mode = develop, debug
```

Next, I opened the settings and added the following settings in the server:

[image]

After all that I ran `docker-compose up -d --build` and it didn't work. I rechecked everything and still nothing...

I'm new to docker and any help would be appreciated...thanks

Comment: "PHP | Servers" on your screenshot -- it's done wrong. Host means host and not URL, port is a website port and not Xdebug. Better: 1) delete it 2) use phone handle icon (make the IDE listen for any incoming debug connections) 3) and once the request comes, it will show the popup that will help you set up this "PHP | Servers" entry. Also enable Xdebug log in php.ini and try to debug -- it will show where it tries to connect to and what the outcome is etc. You can also see `xdebug_info()` output to check if values are what yo have set and see some diagnostic messages.

Comment: @LazyOne i had also deleted it and reloaded the page by putting a debugging point + making the phone handle icon turned on...still got nothing

Comment: So what your Xdebug log has to say? ALSO: 1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw 2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4opFac50Vwo